# Google Script updating Google Sheet data from web app - formatting a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So during the internet course I learned how to connect my data in Google Sheet to a Web App and how to update my data in sheets. Everything looks good, I have a html table where I can change values and they will update my Google Sheet. But I want to do some modifications and don't really know how. I would like to achieve 2 things: if a specific word is found in one of the cells, I would like the whole row to change color, for example, to red if in any cell is word "cat" and second problem - I would like to create another column which in each row would display the options to choose from (always the same 3 options in the form of a drop down list) and after selecting one of them the data in the spreadsheet would be updated to the choosen option. Not quite sure which part of the code I should modify.

Here is my code:

```
function onOpen() {
 var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
 ui.createMenu('Options').addItem('PopUp','showDialog').addToUi();  
}

function showDialog(){
 var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("page-html");
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1iiIkFURQLkqQOLXETe2IZPRhWFbZTELkwmP6IzHpDRo");
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Test");
 var range = sheet.getDataRange();
 var values = range.getValues();
 htmlTemplate.data = values;
 var html =  htmlTemplate.evaluate().setHeight(1200).setWidth(600);
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html,"My data")
}



function doGet(){
 var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("page-html");
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1iiIkFURQLkqQOLXETe2IZPRhWFbZTELkwmP6IzHpDRo");
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Test");
 var range = sheet.getDataRange();
 var values = range.getValues();
 htmlTemplate.data = values;
 var html = htmlTemplate.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
 return html;
}


function sheetUpdate(r,c,v){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1iiIkFURQLkqQOLXETe2IZPRhWFbZTELkwmP6IzHpDRo");
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Test");
 var range = sheet.getDataRange();
 var values = range.getValues();
 values[r][c] = v;
 range.setValues(values);
 var data = {
   'info':'Success! You changed value to: '+v
 };
 return data;

}
```

And here is HTML code:

```
<script>
var datags = <?!= JSON.stringify(data) ?>;
console.log(datags);
</script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
   <meta charset ="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
      td {
      font-style: 10px;

      }
    </style>

</head>

<body> 
  <div class="container">
      <div id="flashMessage"></div>
      <div id="output"></div>
  </div>



  <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
       $(function () {
            var row = '<table class="table">';
            for(var i=0;i < (datags.length); i++){
                if(i != 0 ){
                   row+='<tr>';
                }
                else {
                   row+='<thead class ="thead-dark"><tr>';
                }
                for(var j=0;j < datags[i].length; j++){
                    if(datags[i][j]){
                       if(i != 0 ){
                          row=row+'<td ><input data-row ="'+i+'" data-col="'+j+'" type="text" value="'+datags[i][j]+'" class="dtValue"></td>'
                       }
                       else {
                           row=row+'<th>'+datags[i][j]+'</th>';
                       }

                    }

               }
               if(i != 0 ){
                  row+='</tr>';
               }
               else {
                   row+='</thead></tr>';
               }
           }
           $('#output').html(row);
           $('#output').on('change','.dtValue',function(){
              console.log(this.dataset.row, this.dataset.col, this.value);
              google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
             .sheetUpdate(this.dataset.row, this.dataset.col, this.value);
           });
        })

        function onSuccess(data) {
            $('#flashMessage').html('<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">'+data.info+'</div>');
        }

   </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you want to cahnge the color of the row in the spreadsheet or in your html table?

Comment: HTML Table, I should mention that, sorry